# How can we make a nuclear weapon more effective in shielding us against asteroids?

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

I know that nuclear weapons do not produce the nuclear blast as it would at see level. But would the thermal blast produce any trust to push any asteroid away? If so, how could we improve the effectiveness of its thermal blast?

Comment: Why would you even want to use a nuclear weapon for this purpose? That's Hollywood stuff. There are other techniques that make more sense physically.

Comment: @Ben Crowell Can you care to elaborate?